# Connection to "server name" closed by remote host

Tags: ssh, freenas

I just set up SSH on my freeNAS server. However every time I connect I get kicked out right away. I get the following message:

```
Connection to (my server name) closed by remote host.
```

Anybody knows why this happens?

This is the server log for SSH services:

```
Oct 9 09:35:52 sshd[2389]: Did not receive identification string from 204.16.252.112 
Oct 9 09:36:22 sshd[2390]: Did not receive identification string from 69.163.149.200 
Oct 9 09:36:44 sshd[2391]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Version;Remote: 192.168.1.1-55235;Protocol: 2.0;Client: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 
Oct 9 09:36:54 sshd[2391]: Accepted password for "username" from 192.168.1.1 port 55235 ssh2
```

Comment: This is the server log for SSH services:
Oct 9 09:35:52  sshd[2389]: Did not receive identification string from 204.16.252.112
Oct 9 09:36:22  sshd[2390]: Did not receive identification string from 69.163.149.200
Oct 9 09:36:44  sshd[2391]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Version;Remote: 192.168.1.1-55235;Protocol: 2.0;Client: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
Oct 9 09:36:54  sshd[2391]: Accepted password for "username" from 192.168.1.1 port 55235 ssh2

Answer (score 2):

It could happen because

- the server only accepts a SSH protocol version your client doesn't provide,
- the server only allows asymmetric authentication (RSA,DSA) and you provided no key

Try to set the verbose flag on your client. It should give you some hints. Otherwise check the server log.

Answer (score 1):

it means that the TCP connection socket was terminated from the other side. Its a general error and is not specific to SSH.

You might want to check the authentication of your SSH server on whether you have permission to access the SSH.

I am not familiar with the flavour of SSH software you are using, but most SSH servers have some way of outputting debug output to a log. Try to enable that feature to see whats going on.